# Скорость получения элемента по значению у отсортированного ArrayList

Tags: java, коллекции

Может ли поменяться скорость получения элемента по значению у `ArrayList`, если он отсортирован?

Comment: вы имеете в ввиду метод `indexOf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычный поиск в `ArrayList`, производимый с помощью методов `contains` и `indexOf`, работает за *O(n)*.

```
boolean has = list.contains(number);
```

Однако если если список отсортирован, то можно воспользоваться бинарным поиском, который работает за *O(log n)*.

```
boolean has = Collections.binarySearch(list, number) >= 0;
```

---

Для теста производительности использовались:

- Список, состоящий из чисел от `0` до `999999`, расположенных по возрастанию
- Массив, состоящий из 1000 случайных чисел со значениями от `0` до `1999999`, для поиска этих чисел в списке

Среднее время результатов:

```
contains: 1050ms
binary  :    3ms
```

---

Код теста:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
{
    list.add(i);
}
int counter = 0;
Random random = new Random();
int[] numbers = new int[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = random.nextInt(2 * list.size());
}
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int number : numbers)
{
    boolean has = list.contains(number);
    //boolean has = Collections.binarySearch(list, number) >= 0;
    if (has)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка не повлияет на алгоритм поиска, так как алгоритм заключается в переборе с начала и до конца. Но если наиболее часто разыскиваемые элементы будут в начале списка, то это, в среднем, увеличит скорость поиска.